# Getting a Cannot await void, on a method that I have want to await on

Tags: c#, wpf, asynchronous, async-await

I'm on a team writing a WPF app. We have to make it so that when a user hides/shows different columns that it will reflect that in a ReportViewer control on one of the views. In testing we've found that it takes a long time to add the data to the ReportViewer's data sources; sometimes on the order of several seconds to possibly a minute. Too long I think for the users. So I'm trying to use C#'s async and await. However, when I applied await to the line that is the process hog and then compile it, I get an error from the C# compiler, "Cannot await 'void'". In this case, I cannot change what the .NET framework returns, its void. So how do I handle this situation? Here's the code:

```
private async Task GenerateReportAsync()
{
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    dt.Clear();
    int iCols = 0;
    //Get the column names
    if (Columns.Count == 0)     //Make sure it isn't populated twice
    {
        foreach (DataGridColumn col in dataGrid.Columns)
        {
            if (col.Visibility == Visibility.Visible)
            {
                Columns.Add(col.Header.ToString());     //Get the column heading
                iCols++;
            }
        }
    }
    //Create a DataTable from the rows
    var itemsSource = dataGrid.ItemsSource as IEnumerable<Grievance>;
    if (this.rptViewer != null)
    {
        rptViewer.Reset();
    }
    rptViewer.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear();
    if (m_rdl != null)
    {
        m_rdl.Dispose();
    }
    Columns = GetFieldOrder();
    m_rdl = CoreUtils.GenerateRdl(Columns, Columns);
    rptViewer.LocalReport.LoadReportDefinition(m_rdl);
    //the next line is what takes a long time
    await rptViewer.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(new ReportDataSource("MyData", CoreUtils.ToDataTable(itemsSource)));
    rptViewer.RefreshReport();
}
```

Comment: You must have some false belief about what `await` does if you think that awaiting something that takes a long time is a solution to your problem. Can you describe what your beliefs are about `await`? It only makes sense to await something that is *already* asynchronous; do you believe that await *makes* something that is not asynchronous into an asynchronous operation? It does not.

Comment: It is my understanding that using async/await makes it possible to return control to the UI thread, rather than hang it up, waiting for some long working process to finish. But thank you for asking.

Comment: My point is that if the function is void returning *and* already asynchronous then *it should not be taking much time*.  If it is void returning, synchronous, and high latency then there is nothing to `await`. Await manages an existing asynchronous operation. If you have a high latency operation that you'd like to be asynchronous, `await` isn't going to help you. You're going to have to figure out how to make it asynchronous via some other mechanism.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

For methods that are inherently synchronous, you need to wrap them in your own `Task` so you can await it. In your case, I would just use `Task.Run`:

```
await Task.Run(() => 
{
   rptViewer.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(new ReportDataSource("MyData", CoreUtils.ToDataTable(itemsSource)));
});
```

There are other ways to generate a task, but this one is probably the easiest. If this updates a UI component, it will likely throw an exception because those operations must occur on the UI thread. In this case, try to get the UI related piece away from the long-running part and only wrap the long part in the `Task`.

Comment: It is possible that this will throw a cross thread exception because you are accessing UI components like the report viewer from a background thread.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain Absolutely, I have noted this.

Comment: @BradleyDotNET I've taken your suggestion and came up with the following:

    DataTable dtTmp = null;
    await Task.Run(() => dtTmp = CoreUtils.ToDataTable(itemsSource));
    rptViewer.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(new ReportDataSource("MyData", dtTmp));

I didn't know that using await on a UI component would cause an exception. Thanks for the head's up! The above gives control back to the UI thread quickly. Thanks, again..

Comment: @Rod it is not the await that causes the exception it is the Tas.Run that does.

Answer (score 5):

I can almost be certain that the entire line is not the slow line, it is much more likely that `CoreUtils.ToDataTable(itemsSource)` is the slow piece and that is the part that needs to be improved.

You did not include the source of `ToDataTable` so I can't say for sure what the best way would be, the first and best option would be write a new version of the function that leverages async calls internally to create a function that allows you to await it.

```
var data = await CoreUtils.ToDataTableAsync(itemsSource)
rptViewer.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(new ReportDataSource("MyData", data));
```

The second, less performant option is do the slow part on a background thread using `Task.Run` then back on the UI thread set the data source as needed.

```
var data = await Task.Run(() => CoreUtils.ToDataTable(itemsSource));
rptViewer.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(new ReportDataSource("MyData", data));
```