# Cannot Await Void - Parameter within Async Method C#

Tags: c#, wpf, titanium-web-proxy

I'm trying to test the example of the [Titanium Proxy Server](https://github.com/justcoding121/Titanium-Web-Proxy). However, after copying the example within the 'Read Me' section exactly, I am stuck with an error I can't resolve.

Within this method:

```
public async Task OnRequest(object sender, SessionEventArgs e)
{
    Console.WriteLine(e.WebSession.Request.Url);
    var requestHeaders = e.WebSession.Request.Headers;
    var method = e.WebSession.Request.Method.ToUpper();
    if ((method == "POST" || method == "PUT" || method == "PATCH"))
    {
        byte[] bodyBytes = await e.GetRequestBody();
        await e.SetRequestBody(bodyBytes);
        string bodyString = await e.GetRequestBodyAsString();
        await e.SetRequestBodyString(bodyString);
        e.UserData = e.WebSession.Request;
    }
}
```

I am getting errors for the lines `await e.SetRequestBodyString(bodyString);` and `await e.SetRequestBody(bodyBytes);`.

There error message states `Cannot await 'void'` and it is referring to the parameter within the method `SessionEventArgs` as a void method itself.

How do I resolve this? Am I doing something wrong as the example code is specifically as written above?

Comment: Just try to remove await for Set calls.They don't seem to be async.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting a Cannot await void, on a method that I have want to await on](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42233787/getting-a-cannot-await-void-on-a-method-that-i-have-want-to-await-on)

Comment: They changed their API and now it's sync. In previous versions it was async. Install 3.0.8 for example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Their doc is incorrect. It was async (SetRequestBody, SetRequestBodyString), but now it's sync and you get exception like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42233787/getting-a-cannot-await-void-on-a-method-that-i-have-want-to-await-on).

```
public async Task OnRequest(object sender, SessionEventArgs e)
{
    Console.WriteLine(e.WebSession.Request.Url);
    var requestHeaders = e.WebSession.Request.Headers;
    var method = e.WebSession.Request.Method.ToUpper();
    if ((method == "POST" || method == "PUT" || method == "PATCH"))
    {
        byte[] bodyBytes = await e.GetRequestBody();
        e.SetRequestBody(bodyBytes);
        string bodyString = await e.GetRequestBodyAsString();
        e.SetRequestBodyString(bodyString);
        e.UserData = e.WebSession.Request;
    }
}
```