# async await throwing error for Polly code while connecting to Oracle DB

Tags: c#, async-await, polly

Below is the code that I am trying to maintain Consistent Connection with Oracle Database using Polly.

```
public async Task<bool> Execute()
{
    var retryTimes = 3000;
    var waitBetweenExceptions = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10);

    var retryPolicy = await Policy
        .Handle<OracleException>(e => e.Message.Contains("ORA-12543") || e.Message.Contains("ORA-12170"))
        .WaitAndRetry(retryTimes, i => waitBetweenExceptions);

    retryPolicy.Execute(() =>
    {
        string cs = "Data Source=SampleDB;User Id=userid;Password=password;Connection Timeout=600; Max Pool Size=150;";
        using (OracleConnection connection = new OracleConnection(cs))
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
            {
                connection.Open();
                Console.WriteLine("Counter :" + i);
                Thread.Sleep(1000);
                connection.Close();
            }
        }
    });
    return true;
}
```

I am getting error as `Cannot await void` compilation error.. Also, I want to try WaitForever method of Polly.

I tried something like the below question but little confused on how to use it successfully.

[Getting a Cannot await void, on a method that I have want to await on](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42233787/getting-a-cannot-await-void-on-a-method-that-i-have-want-to-await-on)

**EDIT**
**Modified Question for Synchronous way**

I tried the below code and still it is not working...

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Connect connect = new Connect();
        connect.Execute();
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}

public class Connect
{
    public void Execute()
    {
        var retryTimes = 3000;
        var retryableErrorCodes = new[] { "ORA-12543", "ORA-12170" };
        RetryPolicy retryPolicy = Policy
            .Handle<OracleException>(ex => retryableErrorCodes.Any(errorCode => ex.Message.Contains(errorCode)))
            .WaitAndRetry(retryTimes, _ => TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));

        retryPolicy.Execute(() =>
        {
            string cs = "Data Source=SampleDB;User Id=userid;Password=password;Connection Timeout=600; Max Pool Size=150;";
            using (OracleConnection connection = new OracleConnection(cs))
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
                {
                    connection.Open();
                    Console.WriteLine("Counter :" + i);
                    Thread.Sleep(1000);
                    connection.Close();
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

I tried using Synchronous way. But, after disconnecting the Network cable, it just silently stops but does not Auto Reconnect.

Comment: In the `Polly-Samples` given in the `GitHub`, they are using connectivity through HTTP protocols. But here I need with connection to Oracle Database.

Comment: I am also ok with using the same function but to resolve, async and await with bool  or any other relevant datatypes.

Comment: Could you please elaborate this *still it is not working...*? What is the expected behaviour and what is the observed?

Comment: First the Counter increments every second and at this time, if I disconnect the cable between the program and Oracle DB, the Counter stops and does not retry again to connect to the Database.

Comment: It won't print the actual counter since the `connection.Open` fails that's why you won't reach the `Console.WriteLine` command. Please also note that if the `connection.Open` or `connection.Close` fails then the whole delegate restarts after 10 seconds delay. This means that the `for` loop will start 0 again.

Comment: Yeah it is working fine now. It continues from where it is left. The problem with my code is I was using `Console.ReadKey()`. So, it is not continuing. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The to be decorated code is either `sync` or `async`.

### Sync case

#### Policy declaration

```cs
var retryableErrorCodes = new[] { "ORA-12543", "ORA-12170" };
RetryPolicy retryPolicy = Policy
    .Handle<OracleException>(ex => retryableErrorCodes.Any(errorCode => ex.Message.Contains(errorCode)))
    .WaitAndRetry(retryTimes, _ => TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
```

#### Policy usage

```cs
retryPolicy.Execute(() => 
{
  //...
});
```

### Async case

#### Policy declaration

```cs
var retryableErrorCodes = new[] { "ORA-12543", "ORA-12170" };
AsyncRetryPolicy retryPolicy = Policy
    .Handle<OracleException>(ex => retryableErrorCodes.Any(errorCode => ex.Message.Contains(errorCode)))
    .WaitAndRetryAsync(retryTimes, _ => TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
```

#### Policy usage

```cs
await retryPolicy.ExecuteAsync((ct) =>
{
  //...
}, CancellationToken.None);
```

---

`WaitAndRetryForever` and `WaitAndRetryForeverAsync` would be same but you don't have to specify there the maximum retry count.

Comment: Still somewhere I am stuck. Edited the Question. Please correct me where I went wrong.

Comment: @Ch. Your to be decorated code is not async, so you should use the sync version. Please amend your question with sync version and after that I'll do my best to help you.

Comment: Modified the Question for Synchronous way.