# Polly not handling OracleExceptions ORA-03113 and ORA-03114 properly

Tags: c#, oracle, polly

My previous question on Polly and Oracle Connectivity is as below

[async await throwing error for Polly code while connecting to Oracle DB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67279586/async-await-throwing-error-for-polly-code-while-connecting-to-oracle-db)

Extending this, I am trying to handle multiple Oracle Exceptions based on connectivity along with FTP connection. It is able to handle FTP Exceptions properly. But when it comes to Oracle, it is not able to handle 0RA-03113 and ORA-03114

This is the code I have implemented..

```
static void Main()
    {
        var retryTimes = 100;
        var retryableOracleErrorCodes = new[] { "ORA-03113", "ORA-03114", "ORA-12543", "ORA-12170", "ORA-12154"  };

        RetryPolicy retryPolicyFTP = Policy
            .Handle<Xceed.Ftp.FtpInvalidStateException>()
            .WaitAndRetry(retryTimes, _ => TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));

        RetryPolicy retryPolicyFTP1 = Policy
            .Handle<Xceed.Ftp.FtpIOException>()
            .WaitAndRetry(retryTimes, _ => TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));

        RetryPolicy retryPolicyOracle = Policy
            .Handle<OracleException>(ex => retryableOracleErrorCodes.Any(errorCode => ex.Message.Contains(errorCode)))
            .RetryForever();

        retryPolicyFTP.Execute(() =>
        {
            retryPolicyFTP1.Execute(() =>
            {
                retryPolicyOracle.Execute(() =>
                {
                    ApplicationMain applicationMain = new ApplicationMain();
                    applicationMain.Start();
                });
            });
        });
    }
```

Could you please throw light on this... why it is not able to handle particular Oracle Exceptions..I mean if I break the connection between Program and Oracle DB, it should go silent without throwing that exceptions and again when connection is available, it should be able to retrieve the database records..

Why it is not going silent and why it is breaking...for ORA-03113 & ORA-03114. The error thrown is shown below..

[image]

The detailed exception is as below..

```
36722763    Source.FtpInternal1.Poll    Failed  2021-04-30 08:40:00 2021-04- 
30 08:40:04     Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleException ORA-03113: end-of- 
file on communication channel
Process ID: 149519
Session ID: 1655 Serial number: 65101    at 
Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleException.HandleErrorHelper(Int32 errCode, 
OracleConnection conn, IntPtr opsErrCtx, OpoSqlValCtx* pOpoSqlValCtx, Object 
src, String procedure, Boolean bCheck)
at Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleException.HandleError(Int32 errCode, 
OracleConnection conn, String procedure, IntPtr opsErrCtx, OpoSqlValCtx* 
pOpoSqlValCtx, Object src, Boolean bCheck)
at Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleCommand.ExecuteReader(Boolean requery, 
Boolean fillRequest, CommandBehavior behavior)
at Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleCommand.ExecuteReader()
at Data.MetaRecord.Fill(DataTable dataTable, RecordCommand recordCommand, 
Object[] parameterValues, FillResultType fillResultType) in 
C:\Data\MetaRecord.cs:line 1348
at Data.MetaRecord.FillWithComposites(RecordCommandCompositeCollection 
recordCommandComposites, RecordCommandComposite parentRecordCommandComposite, 
Object[] parameterValues, FillResultType fillResultType) in 
C:\Data\MetaRecord.cs:line 1537
at Data.MetaRecord.FillWithComposites(RecordCommandCompositeCollection 
recordCommandComposites, RecordCommandComposite parentRecordCommandComposite, 
Object[] parameterValues, FillResultType fillResultType) in 
C:\Data\MetaRecord.cs:line 1551
at Data.MetaRecord.FillWithComposites(RecordCommandCompositeCollection 
recordCommandComposites, RecordCommandComposite parentRecordCommandComposite, 
Object[] parameterValues, FillResultType fillResultType) in 
C:\Data\MetaRecord.cs:line 1551
at Data.MetaRecord.RetrieveByPrimaryKey(RecordRetrieveAttributes 
recordRetrieveAttributes, Object[] primaryKeyValues) in 
C:\Data\MetaRecord.cs:line 1830
at Data.MetaRecord.GetRecordByPrimaryKey(RecordGetAttributes 
recordGetAttributes, Object[] primaryKeyValues) in C:\Data\MetaRecord.cs:line 
873
at Data.MetaRecord.GetRecordByPrimaryKey(Object[] primaryKeyValues) in 
C:\Data\MetaRecord.cs:line 923
at Processors.ExecuteInfo.GetAndRegisterRecord(RecordType recordType, 
Object[] primaryKeyValues) in C:\Core\Processors\ExecuteInfo.cs:line 143
at Processors.InternalPoll.ProcessExecute(DataTransaction dataTransaction, 
ExecuteInfo executeInfo, ProcessInfo processInfo) in 
C:\Core\Processors\InternalPoll.cs:line 67
at Processors.Processor.Execute(ExecuteInfo executeInfo, ProcessInfo 
processInfo) in C:\Core\Processors\Processor.cs:line 184
```

This is the final code I have prepared but still it is not throwing OracleException message

```
var retryTimes = 100;
var retryableOracleErrorCodes = new[] { "ORA-03113", "ORA-03114", "ORA-12543", "ORA-12170", "ORA-12154" };

RetryPolicy retryPolicyFTP = Policy
    .Handle<Xceed.Ftp.FtpInvalidStateException>().Or<Xceed.Ftp.FtpIOException>()
    .WaitAndRetry(retryTimes, _ => TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));

RetryPolicy retryPolicyOracle = Policy
    .Handle<OracleException>(ex => retryableOracleErrorCodes
                                    .Any(errorCode => ex.ToString().Contains(errorCode)))
    .RetryForever();

Policy.Wrap(retryPolicyFTP, retryPolicyOracle).Execute(() =>
{
    try
    {
         ApplicationMain applicationMain = new ApplicationMain();
         applicationMain.Start();
    }
    catch (OracleException oraEx)
    {
         MessageBox.Show(oraEx.Message.ToString());
    }
});
```

Got the below message after adding `.Or<Exception>()` to the Final Code

```
Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleException ORA-03114: not connected to ORACLE    at Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleException.HandleErrorHelper(Int32 errCode, OracleConnection conn, IntPtr opsErrCtx, OpoSqlValCtx* pOpoSqlValCtx, Object src, String procedure, Boolean bCheck)
   at Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleException.HandleError(Int32 errCode, OracleConnection conn, String procedure, IntPtr opsErrCtx, OpoSqlValCtx* pOpoSqlValCtx, Object src)
   at Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
   at Data.OraclePackageCommand.ExecuteNonQuery(OracleTransaction transaction) in C:\Core\Data\OraclePackageCommand.cs:line 74
   at Data.OraclePackageCommand.ExecuteNonQuery() in C:\Core\Data\OraclePackageCommand.cs:line 63
   at Data.OraclePackage.ExecuteServerHeartbeat(Int32 serverId, Int32 heartbeatInterval, DateTime processTime, Int32& processingStatusId, DateTime& lastHeartbeatTime, DateTime& nextHeartbeatTime, Int32& availableProcessCount, Boolean& recordModificationExists) in C:\Core\Data\OraclePackage.cs:line 2385
   at Processors.ServerInfo.Heartbeat(DateTime processTime, ServerProcessingStatus& heartbeatProcessingStatus, Int32& availableProcessCount, Boolean& recordModificationExists) in C:\Core\Processors\ServerInfo.cs:line 252
   at Processors.ServerManager.ThreadStart() in C:\Core\Processors\ServerManager.cs:line 337
```

Comment: Please post the actual exception text, not a picture of it. Thank you!

Comment: Added the Oracle Exception in the Question.

Comment: Did you debug into the lambda?

Comment: You mean the Retry expression? It does not come to the lambda expression once the VPN Adapter is disconnected.

Comment: What is the way of debugging this?

Comment: Try replacing the code inside the policy wrappers with: throw new OracleException("ORA-03113"); This will show you if the policy is being fired at all.

Comment: And also remove the other wrappers in case that has something to do with it

Comment: You should use `Policy.Wrap` to define an [escalation](https://github.com/peter-csala/resilience-service-design/blob/main/resilience.md#esc) rather than nesting the `Execute` calls. `var strategy = Policy.Wrap(retryPolicyFTP, retryPolicyFTP1, retryPolicyOracle) `

Comment: Please also note that you can combine the `retryPolicyFTP`, `retryPolicyFTP1` policies. You need to use `Or` like this: `.Handle<Xceed.Ftp.FtpInvalidStateException>().Or<Xceed.Ftp.FtpIOException>().WaitAndRetry(...)`

Comment: The new code is posted in the Question. But still it does not throw OracleException and also it is displaying the same message i.e., ORA-03113 and ORA-03114 messages are showing as in the attached picture. No change at all.

Comment: Even I tried with Exception instead of OracleException where the `applicationMain.Start` is called and still no change at all. It is `NOT` throwing error message but the errors are coming in the application `DataGrid` in the Windows based Application.

Comment: None of your policies are set up to trigger for `Exception`. Did you add `.Or<Exception>()` to your `retryPolicyOracle`?

Comment: The Question is modified. I have got ORA-03114 message after adding the `.Or<Exception>()` to the code.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231785/discussion-between-peter-csala-and-ch).

Comment: @Ch. I think I've found the root cause, please check my post.

Comment: @PeterCsala, Sorry for unmarking your solution. I am eagerly trying to get your attention on one point. How can we implement the same RetryPolicy in a windows based application where on click of a button, it fetches FTP files from the different Server and stores locally and updates Oracle Database. When I implement the same Retry at applicationMain.Start(), it always stops at Application.Run() method and does not run further. Here it is trying to restart the whole windows application instead of applying to a particular screen. Does Polly supports Windows based Applications in C#?

Comment: @Ch. The Polly library is environment agnostic. In other words it does not matter that you use it inside an ASP.NET webapp or inside a Console application. It behaves in the same way. So, the above mentioned problem does not related to Polly.

Comment: @Ch. I think this problem is related to the usage. I suggest to open a new question which is focusing on the consumer-side. You have already altered your question a couple of times :)

Comment: Ok sure. I will open a new question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TL;DR: I think the root cause of your problem is the swallowed exception.

```cs
try
{
     ApplicationMain applicationMain = new ApplicationMain();
     applicationMain.Start();
}
catch (OracleException oraEx)
{
     MessageBox.Show(oraEx.Message.ToString());
}
```

When an `OracleException` is thrown then it is shown on the UI
but then the method ends and will not trigger any policy.

---

In order to be able to reproduce your problem I've changed the following things:

- I've replaced the 3rd party exceptions to built-in ones

  - `FtpInvalidStateException` >> `NotSupportedException`
  - `OracleException` >> `ArgumentException`
- I've defined two delegates for each `onRetry` to print out the exception message when the policy is triggered
- I've changed the max retry and wait period between retries to smaller
- I've extracted the *to be decorated* piece of code into a separate function, called `FaultyMethod`
- Lastly I've made the `FaultyMethod` really faulty :)

#### Main with policy declarations and usage

```cs
static readonly string[] retryableErrorCodes = 
    new[] { "ORA-03113", "ORA-03114", "ORA-12543", "ORA-12170", "ORA-12154" };
const int retryTimes = 3;

static void Main()
{
    RetryPolicy retryForNotSupported = Policy
        .Handle<NotSupportedException>()
        .WaitAndRetry(
            retryTimes,
            _ => TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1),
            (ex, ts) => Console.WriteLine(ex.Message));

    RetryPolicy retryForArgument = Policy
        .Handle<ArgumentException>(ex =>
            retryableErrorCodes.Any(errorCode => ex.Message.Contains(errorCode)))
        .RetryForever(ex => Console.WriteLine(ex.Message));

    try
    {
        Policy.Wrap(retryForNotSupported, retryForArgument).Execute(FaultyMethod);
    } catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex);
        Environment.Exit(-1);
    }
    Console.WriteLine("Finished");
}
```

#### The to be decorated function

```cs
static int errorCount = -1;
static void FaultyMethod()
{
    try
    {
        if (++errorCount >= retryableErrorCodes.Length)
            throw new NotSupportedException();
        throw new ArgumentException($"{retryableErrorCodes[errorCount]}");
    }
    catch (ArgumentException ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

If you run this application you will see the following:

```
ORA-03113
Finished
```

1. `ArgumentException` is thrown with message `ORA-03113`
2. The exception is catched inside the `FaultyMethod` and its message is printed out
3. None of the retry policies are triggered
4. No exception is thrown by the `Policy`'s `Execute` that's why *Finished* is printed

---

Now let's change the code to throw `NotSupportedException` instead

```cs
static void FaultyMethod()
{
    try
    {
        if(++errorCount <= retryTimes)
            throw new NotSupportedException();
        
        //if (++errorCount >= retryableErrorCodes.Length) 
        //    throw new ArgumentException($"{retryableErrorCodes[errorCount]}");
    }
    catch (ArgumentException ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Then the output will be:

```
Specified method is not supported.
Specified method is not supported.
Specified method is not supported.
System.NotSupportedException: Specified method is not supported.
...
```

1. `FaultyMethod` throws `NotSupportedException`
2. Its catch block does not catch this exception
3. Inner retry policy checks whether it is a handled exception from its perspective
4. **No, it's not** that's why it escalates the problem to the outer policy
5. Outer retry policy checks whether it is a handled exception from its perspective
6. **Yes, it is** that's why it waits 1 second before initiates a new retry
7. This exact same sequence (from 1 to 6) repeats 2 more times
8. When the outer policy reaches its retry count threshold then it will throw the original exception the `NotSupportedException`
9. `Main`'s try-catch will catch that and it will print it out then **exits**

---

So, if you remove the try-catch from the `FaultyMethod`

```cs
static void FaultyMethod()
{
    if (++errorCount >= retryableErrorCodes.Length)
        throw new NotSupportedException();
    throw new ArgumentException($"{retryableErrorCodes[errorCount]}");
}
```

then the output will look like this:

```
ORA-03113
ORA-03114
ORA-12543
ORA-12170
ORA-12154
Specified method is not supported.
Specified method is not supported.
Specified method is not supported.
System.NotSupportedException: Specified method is not supported.
```

- All `ArgumentException` is handled by the inner policy without exceeding its retry count (infinite)
- All `NotSupportedException` is handled by the outer policy before exceeding its retry count (3)